# Show that $\sum _ {i=1} ^{\lg n - 1} \frac 1 {\lg n - i} = \sum _{i=1} ^{\lg n - 1} \frac 1 i$

Tags: summation

I couldn't understand this summation:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lg n - 1} \frac{1}{\lg n -i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lg n - 1} \frac{1}{i} .$$

How did author transform LHS to RHS? Can you describe in detail or post link for explanation? Is there any formula using which we can prove LHS = RHS?

Comment: Note that I have changed $\log$ into $\lg$, as it was in your original post. If this is not correct, please change it back (usually, $\log$ is computed in base $\rm e$, while $\lg$ is in base $10$).

Comment: Thanks Alex.
Here log has base of 2, but it shouldn't matter as this is related to analysis of complexity.

Comment: It's just a change in indexing.  Both sides have the same terms.  The LHS you are listing the terms from lg n down and the RHS you are listing the terms from 1 up.

Comment: Yeah fleablood!! Thats correct, i figured out pretty late. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\lg=\log_m,~$ let $n=m^k,~$ and then reverse the summation-order by substituting $j=k-i.$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{\lg n - 1}{1 \over \lg n - i} & =
-\sum_{i = 1}^{\lg n - 1}{1 \over i - \lg n} =
-\sum_{i = 1 - \lg n}^{-1}\,\,{1 \over i} =
-\sum_{i = \lg n - 1}^{1}\,\,{1 \over -i} =
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{i = 1}^{\lg n - 1}{1 \over i}}}
\end{align}

> In general,
>   $\ds{\sum_{i = m}^{n}a_{i} = \sum_{i = m}^{n}a_{m + n - i}}$.

For example,
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\lg n - 1}{1 \over \lg n - i} =
\sum_{i = 1}^{\lg n - 1}{1 \over
\lg n - \braces{\bracks{1 + \pars{\lg n - 1}} - i}} =
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{i = 1}^{\lg n - 1}{1 \over i}}}
$$